# How Can i detect plugging in/out Oculus touch controllers?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, oculus

I'm editing it again, to make it as simple as I can. I want to have ability in my game (made in unreal engine 4) to detect if Oculus touch controllers are plugged in or not. Below you can find what i did so far.

First of all what i did so far:
In OculusInput.cpp

```
  bool FOculusInput::IsControllerConnected(int32 ControllerIndex) const
    {
        for (const FOculusTouchControllerPair& ControllerPair : ControllerPairs)
        {
            if (ControllerPair.UnrealControllerIndex == ControllerIndex)
            {
                const FOculusTouchControllerState& ControllerState = ControllerPair.ControllerStates[(int32)EControllerHand::Left];

                if (ControllerState.bIsConnected)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Then I've added this in IMotionController.h :

```
virtual bool IsControllerConnected(int32 ControllerIndex)const
    {
        return false;
    }
```

Finally in MyGameMode I've added this:

```
UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable, Category = "Controller")
    bool IsTouchConnected(int32 ControllerIndex);

TSharedPtr<IMotionController> MotionController;
```

and in .cpp

```
bool AMyGameMode::IsTouchConnected(int32 ControllerIndex)
{

    if (!MotionController.IsValid())
    {
    MotionController.Get(); //this doesn't work
    }

    if (MotionController.IsValid())
    {
        return MotionController->IsControllerConnected(ControllerIndex);
    }
    return false;
}
```

So this is how it should work:
1.I'm calling function AMyGameMode::IsTouchConnected();
2.Then it calls IMotionController::IsControllerConnected via MotionController pointer.
3.Then due to being overriten in OculusInput, Oculus Function is called and returns my main target.

What is wrong now:

MotionController pointer seems to always be nullptr. I have no idea how to make it work.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: I'm commenting becouse I've made some progress in this issue i think :)

Comment: I think you misread the words **minimal** and **complete** that I wrote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've finally made it, so i wanted to post it here for anyone searching for it.

First of all what you want to do is add to IMotionController new function:

```
virtual bool IsControllerConnected(int32 ControllerIndex)const
    {
        return false;
    }
```

Then you go to OculusInput and add this:

.h

```
virtual bool IsControllerConnected(int32 ControllerIndex)const override;
```

.cpp

```
bool FOculusInput::IsControllerConnected(int32 ControllerIndex) const
{
    for (const FOculusTouchControllerPair& ControllerPair : ControllerPairs)
    {
        if (ControllerPair.UnrealControllerIndex == ControllerIndex)
        {
            const FOculusTouchControllerState& ControllerState = ControllerPair.ControllerStates[(int32)EControllerHand::Left];

            if (ControllerState.bIsConnected)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Finally in your class you are adding this:

.h

```
#include "MotionControllerComponent.h"


UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable, Category = "Controller")
    bool IsTouchConnected(int32 ControllerIndex);


TSharedPtr<class UMotionControllerComponent> MCComponent;
```

.cpp

```
bool YourClass::IsTouchConnected(int32 ControllerIndex)
{
    TArray<IMotionController*> controllers = IModularFeatures::Get().GetModularFeatureImplementations<IMotionController>(IMotionController::GetModularFeatureName());

    for (IMotionController* MotionController : controllers)
    {
        return MotionController->IsControllerConnected(ControllerIndex);
    }
    return false;
}
```

With this code I can successfully check if my touch controller (left in this case) is connected or not :) Hope i could help anyone with it!